# How to prevent user from turning off app notifications

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm trying to find out how to achieve the following:

[image]

The people in the chat hinted that it may be a system-app setting, but that was as far as I could get.
Even being a system-app setting I cannot find it anywhere, so what do I need to do in order for my app to be able to do the same thing?

Before anyone comes with comments stating how user-unfriendly this is and not to do it, this is not for a generic app but for a business centered work environment where it is important to ensure the notifications are not turned off, especially when the devices can be passed onto other colleagues between shifts and one of them could've turned something off and the others are not aware of.

Comment: Ordinary apps can't do this. You might look into the device owner APIs.

Comment: @CommonsWare I was not able to find any device owner API that allowed notifications to not be turned off. The closest thing I could find was the ability to disable the status bar entirely.

Comment: Then presumably it is only available for device manufacturers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems this is only possible with system apps or at least with apps that have special access - which is not available to apps normally installed from the PlayStore or similar.

Answer (score -2):

You can specify which app features your app requires.  Such that if they turn off the feature, or don't have the feature, the app won't run.  In the manifest file you would declare something like:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name= "android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH" />
```

In your app, you would need to check if the user has granted the permission to RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH and if not, display an error message and force them to exit the app.

Comment: This is not what this question is about.